# sed -E for groups

Tags: sed, regular-expression

This

```
$echo '| foo | bar | baz |' | sed 's@^|[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|.*@\1@'
```

return `bar` as desired. How would I do the same with opt `-E`?

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo '| foo | bar | baz |' | sed -E 's@^\|[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|.*@\1@'
 bar
```

Notes:

1. In extended regex, groups are made with `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`.
2. In extended regex, `|` generally means alternation.  To interpret it as a character, it needs to be escaped.  (The exception to this rule is inside `[...]` where `|` is just a regular character.

#### Alternative: using awk

```
$ echo '| foo | bar | baz |' | awk -F\| '{print $3}'
 bar
```

Comment: I had tried groups without \ but forgot \|. Yeah, awk more straightforward.

Comment: @Erwann Yes, that's understandable.  I try to use ERE all the time just so I don't have to keep track of that stuff.

Comment: Using this line of thinking, I was hoping this would return `1964`, instead it returns `196}`: `$ echo " , year={1964}}" | sed -E 's/.*year=\{(.+)[^\}]\}/\1/'`

Comment: @Erwann Try: `echo " , year={1964}}" | sed -E 's/.*year=\{(.+[^}]).*/\1/'`

Comment: Thanks. `\}` needed in some places, `}` in others?

Comment: @Erwann Three points:  (a) The capture group needed to include `[^}]`.  So, we needed `(.+[^}])` instead of `(.+)[^}]`.  Otherwise, the last digit would be missing. (b) we needed to throw away both `}`, not just the first.  So, we replaced `\}` with `.*`.  As the least important point,  (c) inside `[...]`, `}` is just a regular character and doesn't need to be escaped.  `[^\}]` actually means any character except `}` or `\`.

Comment: @Erwann A slightly simpler form would be:  `sed -E 's/.*year=\{([^}]*).*/\1/'`

Comment: I didn't spot the format issue in time, so let me correct:  `[^\}]` actually means any character except `}` or `\\`.

Comment: Actually it does not work: `$ echo " , year={1964}, other}" | sed -E 's/.*year=\{(.+[^}]).*/\1/'` returns `1964}, other`

Comment: @Erwann If you add things after the `}`, then use `sed -E 's/.*year=\{([^}]*).*/\1/'`